# Flutter Splash Screen Animation

Tags: flutter, animation, splash-screen

I want to create a custom animated splash screen like [the splash screen of Uber iOS App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QUXtUz1JI3Py8zdCjLF_tJ8oft6oTxud/view?usp=sharing):
I tried to create two containers and animate them but not even close to what Uber did.
Is there any way to do it programmatically instead of creating the animation and import it within the app?

Comment: Share your code so others can give suggession.

Comment: @DAVEchintan trust me, my code is not functioning as planned, if there's any ideas that's will be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not detailed so all I can do is giving a topic to you to train.
Flutter has a nice capability of animating things, but if the animation is too complicated, I prefer pre-built animations like AfterEffect or sth like that.

You can possibly do what you want using [AnimatedContainer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI-8QHpGIP4). But first, you need to gather more than basic animation knowledge in this area, so, [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) is the topic you need to dig..

Answer (score 0):

One way is using CustomPainter, but it is also possible to use other built-in flutter widgets like explained here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations